# Did LifeHacks just become a public beta?

Tags: discussion

It appears that the various controls that were open to me during the private beta have changed. Does that mean that we have been promoted to a public beta?

Comment: Ooh you beat me to it! I'll leave mine open as it has some other info!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.

The emails announcing this are sent out in batches and should make their way out to everyone's mailboxes ... eventually.